# Não esta a eliminar da DataBase os dados que eu quero

Tags: java, android

Tenho este código que supostamente apaga da dataBase a data que eu meto no método. Mas não esta a apagar da dataBase e não percebo porque.
Aqui esta as informações :

```
    public void deleteRowWhitDate(String date){
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+ COL_4 + " = " + date ;
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

Tenho a certeza que a dataBase contem a data que meto em date.

```
      public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Exames_table";
    public static final String COL_4 = "DIA";
```

Fazendo o

```
Log.d("debug",query);
```

Obtive :

> DELETE FROM Exames_table WHERE DIA = 30-07-2017

Comment: Debuga a operação e obtenha a string final da variável query e tente executar diretamente no banco.

Comment: Faz `Log.d("debug", query);` antes de ela ser executada em `database.execSQL(query);` e diz o que tem

Comment: Qual o tipo você usou quando criou a coluna "DIA" na tabela (Text, INTEGER, etc) e diz um exemplo de valor que você passa na String date.

Comment: Exemplo : 30-07-2017 , Usei o tipo Text

Comment: @Isac Deu isto DELETE FROM Exames_table WHERE DIA = 30-07-2017

Comment: @PedroGouveia acredito que a sintaxe do sql esteja errada! Tente executar este sql em algum SGBD. Possivelmente a data não está registrada dessa forma (30-07-2017) no banco. E caso esteja é necessário colocar o caracter ' para funcionar. Exemplo: DELETE FROM Exames_table WHERE DIA = '30-07-2017'

Comment: @KaranPereira Sim meter os ' ajudou ja funcionou obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você definiu a coluna como TEXT, então o problema é que faltou plics (') no parâmetro de comparação da sua query SQL. Deveria estar sim:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+ COL_4 + " = '" + date + "'";
```